# making hash more safe with a salt

Tags: java, hash, salt

Im new here, so please correct me on anything!

I was assigned to do a basic java program where i register and authenticate users, storing the username and the password in a .txt file. The password is stored as an MD5 hash. Also, i needed to make another program to try brute-forcing the .txt file to find the passwords, and measure the time needed to do so.

i managed to do that(suffering a bit), and the last step is to find and implement a way to reduce the chances of this brute-forcing to work. I searched a lot about it, and apart from people saying to use another safer method of storing passwords, the only thing i found useful(which i heard of before so i searched for it) was using salts, Which i know that they are concatenated within the password before hashing, and then both hash and salt are stored.

But i dont think this would work in this occasion, as the salt would also be  stored in the .txt file, thus, even taking longer due to the bigger possible range of combinations, i could still do a brute force where i try a combination and add the salt in the .txt to it, then hash it and compare to the hash stored in the .txt.

Is this a viable way to make the brute force harder(at least in this assignment, for learning purposes) as it takes more time, or is there any other methods to do so?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Adding a salt will make the process more secure. Do a search on 'rainbow tables'. Salting solves this problem. Btw, I think the point of making you try to brute force the password and measure the time is to demonstrate how much better using a salt is.

Comment: The intention of both the (more recent) hashing algorithms and salting is to make the process - 1: Harder to generate "lookup" tables; 2: Computationally prohibitive to break.  They're not designed to make it impossible, just as hard as is reasonably possible.  If you want to make it more difficult, then consider using a different hashing algorithm (along with salts)

Comment: This question would probably get better answers on the [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/), especially since you're not asking for implementation. I don't see how rainbow tables would be relevant since you're brute-forcing the password. You can consider the salt as added entropy but that's definitely not a great way to increase brute-force time.

Comment: *"implement a way to reduce the chances of this brute-forcing to work"* Don't use MD5.

Comment: I don't think salts will make any difference for brute forcing MD5.  Are you allowed to change the MD5 to return a 256 bit result?  that would require more work to brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all. md5-Hash is deprecated. Please use sha256 or sha512 instead.

The salt should not stored inside the text file. It is a config parameter of your programm.

Now, you can use your secret salt and the password to generate the hash.

```
hashedPw = sha256(salt + password)
```

This avoids that an attacker can retrieve the original password from look it up in an lookup table. (https://crackstation.net/)

Additionally you can encrypt your passwords with AES-Algorithm.